# Hash table with double hashing

Tags: c, hash-map

I writing a hash table with double hashing. **This code works ONLY with ASCII text files** and finding the number of occurrences of each word in input file! Please point out mistakes and shortcomings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define STRINGSIZE 50 
#define EXP 2 
#define TABLESIZE 100 

struct hashtable {
    int amount; 
    char string[50]; 
};

struct hastable *insert(char *str, struct hashtable *table, int *psize, int *pbusy);
unsigned int hash(const char *str);
unsigned int hash2(const char *str);
int get(char *str, struct hashtable *table, int size);

struct hashtable *rehash(struct hashtable *table, int *size, int *pbusy) {
    int i = 0;
    int size2 = 0;
    int psize2 = *size;
    int result = 0;
    (*size) *= EXP; 
    struct hashtable *temp = (struct hashtable*)calloc(sizeof(struct hashtable), *size);
    *pbusy = 0;

    while (i < psize2) {
        temp = insert(table[i].string, temp, size, pbusy, table[i].amount);
        i++;
    }

    free(table);
    return temp;
}

int get(char *str, struct hashtable *table, int size) {
    unsigned int value = hash(str) % size; 
    int i = 0;

    while (value < size) {

        if (!strcmp(table[value].string, str)) {
            return table[value].amount;
        } 

        value = (hash(str) + i + hash2(str)) % size;
        i++;

        if (value == (size - 1)) 
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

unsigned int hash2(const char *str) {  
    unsigned int hash = 0;

    for(; *str; str++) {
        hash += (unsigned char)(*str);
        hash -= (hash << 13) | (hash >> 19);
    }

    return hash;
}

unsigned int hash(const char *str) {
    static const unsigned int b = 378551;
    unsigned int a = 63689;
    unsigned int hash = 0;

    for (; *str; str++) {
        hash = hash * a + (unsigned char)(*str);
        a *= b;
    }

    return hash;
}

struct hastable *insert(char *str, struct hashtable *table, int *psize, int *pbusy, int amount) {
    unsigned long long int value = 0;

    if ((*pbusy) > ((2 * (*psize)) / 3)) { 
        printf("Rehash... ");
        printf("Table Size = %d", *psize);
        table = rehash(table, psize, pbusy, str);
        printf(" [OK]\n");
    }

    value = hash(str) % (*psize);

    if (!strcmp(table[value].string, str)) { 
        (table[value].amount)++;
    } else if (!strlen(table[value].string)) { 
        strcpy(table[value].string, str); 

        if (!amount){
            table[value].amount++;  
        } else {
            table[value].amount = amount;
        }

        (*pbusy)++; 
    } else if ((strcmp(table[value].string, str)) && (strlen(table[value].string))) { 
        value = (hash(str) + hash2(str)) % (*psize); 
        int i = 0;

        while (value < *psize) {

            if (!strcmp(table[value].string, str)) {
                table[value].amount++;
                break;

            } else if (!strlen(table[value].string)) {
                strcpy(table[value].string, str);

                if (!amount){
                    table[value].amount++; 
                } else {
                    table[value].amount = amount;
                }

                (*pbusy)++; 
                break;
            }

            value = (hash(str) + (i + hash2(str))) % (*psize);
            i++;

        }
    } 

    return table;
}

void WorkWithFile(char *argv[]) {   
    FILE *text = fopen(argv[1], "r"); 

    if (NULL == text) { 
        printf("Error! You was opened empty file or file doesn't exist!\n");
        return;
    } else {
        printf("File was opened\n");
        char string[STRINGSIZE] = { 0 }; 
        int size = TABLESIZE;
        int busy = 0; 
        int *psize = &size;
        int *pbusy = &busy;
        int i = 0;
        struct hashtable *table = (struct hashtable*)calloc(size, sizeof(struct hashtable)); 

        printf("Building HashTable...\n");
        while (fscanf(text, "%s", string) == 1) { 
            table = insert(string, table, psize, pbusy, 0);
        }

        fclose(text); 
        printf("[OK]\n\n");

        while (!strstr(string, "EOF")) {
            printf("Enter Substring : ");
            scanf("%s", string);
            printf("The Number of Occurrences ");
            printf("%d\n\n", get(string, table, size));
        }

        free(table);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Welcome to HashTable Program!\n");

    if (1 < argc) {
        printf("Argument has been Received\n");
        srand(time(NULL));
        WorkWithFile(argv);
    } else {
        printf("The program requires an argument on the command line!\nPlease run this program from console with any arguments.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "if you need more than 3 levels of indentation, you're screwed anyway" - Linus Torvalds

Comment: One think to note is the hashing mechanism you're using although is double hashing is still using linear probing. You can avoid this by doing h1(k) + (k2(k) * 1)) % table_size

Answer (score 3):

A few things to start with (there's probably more though):

- I would give your top level global constants better names. The names you've chosen are very frequent and could cause collisions. I suggest adding a name prefix to the constants, to make sure they are unique to this module. `EXP` is also quite vague. It seems to be the size increase when resizing the table, so we can think of a more descriptive name.

  My suggestion for naming, with the `HT_` prefix for *Hash Table*:

  ```
  #define HT_PAYLOAD_SIZE      50
  #define HT_RESIZE_MULTIPLIER 2
  #define HT_NUM_BUCKETS       100
  ```

  And make sure you use your constants! The `string` field of `hashtable` is using the raw number `50`, which should probably be one of your `#defines` instead.
- In `rehash()`, you got the call to [`calloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/) wrong! The first argument is the number of elements to allocate, the second it the size of each element. This is probably what you wanted:

  ```
  struct hashtable *temp = calloc(*size, sizeof(struct hashtable));
  ```
- Don't cast the result of `malloc/calloc/etc`, actually, never cast from `void*` to `T*` in pure C code, a void pointer converts implicitly to any other pointer type, so the cast is just boilerplate.

  The one exception to this is if you plan on compiling this code as C++. A C++ compiler is much more strict about type castings, so no `void* => T*` conversions are allowed in such case.
- Consider using a `typedef` with your structs to make code less verbose. E.g.:

  ```
  typedef struct {
      int amount; 
      char string[50]; 
  } hashtable;
  ```

  Now you can just use `hashtable` without the `struct` tag everywhere.
- Speaking of `hashtable`, this struct looks more like a *table bucket* then a Hash Table itself. A [Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is usually just a collection of such buckets. You might want to clear that ambiguity by giving it a more accurate name. You should be looking at something along these lines:

  ```
  typedef struct {
      int amount; 
      char string[HT_PAYLOAD_SIZE]; 
  } TableBucket;

  typedef struct {
      unsigned int capacity;
      unsigned int used;
      TableBucket * buckets;
  } HashTable;

  HashTable * rehash(HashTable * ht, unsigned int newCapacity);
  bool insert(HashTable * ht, const char * value);
  ...
  ```

  Notice that now all those parameters are consolidated into a single structure, which makes your public interface a lot cleaner.
- The `char *str` parameter of `insert` is not meant to be modified, so mark it as `const char *` instead.
- Finally, naming your hash functions with the name of the hash algorithm would be much better than just `hash` and `hash2`. Which hashing algorithm is it? E.g.: Is it a `hashCRC32`? A `hashOAT`, `hashFNV`? Embed that info in the name of the function.